# Component Exception in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am getting an error saying:

[image]

As the error suggest I thought it had something to do with the exports in `AppTextInput.js` but everything looks alright in the file(this component is used in other files such as for `SignIn`, `ignOut` and `ConfirmSignUp`):

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, TextInput} from 'react-native';
import {MaterialCommunityIcons} from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';

function AppTextInput({leftIcon, ...otherProps}) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {leftIcon && (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons
          name={leftIcon}
          size={20}
          color="#6e6869"
          style={styles.icon}
        />
      )}
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholderTextColor="#6e6869"
        {...otherProps}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9f9f9',
    borderRadius: 25,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    padding: 15,
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
  icon: {
    marginRight: 10,
  },
  input: {
    width: '80%',
    fontSize: 18,
    color: '#101010',
  },
});

export default AppTextInput;
```

The `Source` on the other hand says the error is coming from `App.js` at `line 28` but I cannot find the error here(the file is much longer but I just included the source from the logs).

```
function App() {
  const [isUserLoggedIn, setUserLoggedIn] = useState('initializing');

  async function checkAuthState() {
    try {
      await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
      console.log('User is signed in');
      setUserLoggedIn('loggedIn');
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('User is not signed in');
      setUserLoggedIn('loggedOut');
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    checkAuthState();
  }, []);

  const AuthenticationNavigator = props => {
    return (
      <AuthenticationStack.Navigator headerMode="none">
        <AuthenticationStack.Screen
          name="SignIn"
          component={SignIn}></AuthenticationStack.Screen>
        <AuthenticationStack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUp} />
        <AuthenticationStack.Screen
          name="ConfirmSignUp"
          component={ConfirmSignUp}
        />
      </AuthenticationStack.Navigator>
    );
  };

  const AppNavigator = props => {
    return (
      <AppStack.Navigator>
        <AppStack.Screen name="Home" component={Home}></AppStack.Screen>
      </AppStack.Navigator>
    );
  };
  const Initializing = () => {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="tomato" />
      </View>
    );
  };

  function updateAuthState(isUserLoggedIn) {
    setUserLoggedIn(isUserLoggedIn);
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {isUserLoggedIn === 'initializing' && <Initializing />}
      {isUserLoggedIn === 'loggedIn' && (
        <AppNavigator updateAuthState={updateAuthState} />
      )}
      {isUserLoggedIn === 'loggedOut' && (
        <AuthenticationNavigator updateAuthState={updateAuthState} />
      )}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

#### Here is the Call Stack as well:

[image]

Comment: react-native is never giving us the right line number BTW

Comment: Ouch, I'll try commenting out the components and seeing which one causes the error.

Comment: please upload your whole app.js file

Comment: Just added it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your App.js component does not render anything, that why exception throw error.

After review your update, I think you are import something does not existing

`import {MaterialCommunityIcons} from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';`

It should be

`import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';`

Comment: I cannot believe this was the error. I also did not add in the Fonts for `react-native-vector-icons` as well. It works as expected now.